# Using graphics object in mousePressed

Tags: java

In the method mousePressed, i can't use any graphics related methods, for example this code will run but won't work

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Control extends BasicGameState {
public static final int ID = 1;

public Graphics g = new Graphics();

public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException{
}

public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
}

public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) {
}

public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y){
    g.drawRect(x,y,2,2);
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

}
```

why can nothing graphics orientated run through the method?

thanks - Shamus

Answer (score 0):

That's not how painting works. Painting is the respnsibilty of the repaint manager.

You need to override the appropriate methods in order to be informed when to paint.

Have a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) (This more about how painting works)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to draw stuff in your mouse event, why not call the `repaint()` function?  Save the graphics commands for the `paint()` function.